# I have issues reading simple text files in python

Tags: python, file, encoding

I just began Python

I have issues reading simple text files in python. I have two situations. I create either a .txt or .docx or .rtf file.
Then I import it with `a=read("file.txt","r")`.

a displays:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='file.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Then I create a variable to read it `b=a.read()`
When I display b, I have either an error message, either a proper displaying but that doesn't only display the content as my course says it should, but displays a lot of things. I will paste both messages below (I have tried with a lot of different text contents in the source file, I cannot seem to see a pattern - when Python says it cannot read the 16th character, it always goes to a simple letter in the original file).

``

```
a=open("file.txt","r")
a
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='file.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
b=a.read()
b
```

When it works, the message is:

```
'{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1671\\cocoasubrtf200\n{\\fonttbl\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 Helvetica;}\n{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}\n{\\*\\expandedcolortbl;;}\n\\paperw11900\\paperh16840\\margl1440\\margr1440\\vieww10800\\viewh8400\\viewkind0\n\\pard\\tx566\\tx1133\\tx1700\\tx2267\\tx2834\\tx3401\\tx3968\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural\\partightenfactor0\n\n\\f0\\fs24 \\cf0
```

this file is vanilla. It only contains letters and dots.}'

Now I try with another file, containing other characters (see below) and it fails.

`

```
a=open("fichier1.docx","r")
a
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='fichier1.docx' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

b=a.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    b=a.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte
```

Second file contains the following:

```
Des tomates
Des carottes
Des herbes de Provences
Du thé
De la cannelle
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to read/write on files in Python like this. You can use:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    print(line)
```

Or you can also store all the lines of a file in a list:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
```

And then you can read a single line using:

```
print(lines[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at this method. However this does not answer my problem at all...

Comment: Have you tried reading the same files you wrote in the question with one of these two methods? And, after this, it keeps prompting the same errors you had?

Comment: With your method, I get

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 2, in <module>
    for line in a:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte

Comment: the file only contains "aaaaaaaaa"

Comment: Can you run from terminal `wc file.txt` and tell me the output?

Comment: MacBook-Pro-de-Sebastien:~ sebastienchabrol$ /Users/sebastienchabrol/Documents/file.docx
-bash: /Users/sebastienchabrol/Documents/file.docx: Permission denied
MacBook-Pro-de-Sebastien:~ sebastienchabrol$ 

I renamed it to "file.docx" btw